# How to set "lxc.mount.auto" in LXD

Tags: lxc, lxd

I came with a [strange problem with LXD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828580/lxd-unable-to-start-container), and I partially solved it.

However, I need to know how to set "lxc.mount.auto" in LXD. In other words, where does the *lxc.mount.auto* value in `/var/log/lxd/container-name/lxc.conf` value come from? and how to set it permanently?

**UPDATE**

According to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxd.html):

> ... Sometimes, however, it may be necessary to talk to the underlying
>   lxc driver itself. This can be done by specifying LXC configuration
>   items in the 'raw.lxc' LXD configuration key. These must be valid
>   items as documented in the lxc.container.conf(5) manual page.

However I haven't found a way to modify or include that raw.lxc

**UPDATE 2**

As far as [I understood](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2015-March/008778.html), this is how you set it:

`lxc config set container-name raw.lxc "lxc.mount.auto=sys"`

It actually works, as I can see it being added into: `/var/log/lxd/container-name/lxc.conf`, for example:

```
lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override sys_time sys_module sys_rawio
lxc.mount.auto = proc:rw sys:rw cgroup:mixed
lxc.autodev = 1
...
lxc.mount.auto=sys
```

However it seems that it does not overwrite the previous rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/746261/where-to-configure-lxd-containers

Comment: Even though my problem was solved by restarting the server, I think this question may be useful if it gets answered someday.